# Non-blocking asynchronous mongo java/scala driver can block thread - how to deal with that?

Tags: java, mongodb, scala, asynchronous

with the non-blocking asynchronous mongo java/scala driver, it is possible to define a wait time and a wait queue size for operations that cannot be executed directly with a free connection.
When settings these values, the mongo driver will make the threads waiting for an available connection.

This behaviour is very dangerous for an application written with non-blocking asynchronous IO in mind.
These applications use a very limited number of threads (= numbers of cores).
Blocking one of these thread can block the whole application.

What would be the recommended way to for this kind of applications?
Should we set all these waiting settings to 0 and handle `MongoWaitQueueFullException` with retries in the application?
Should the driver call an application callback when a connection is free?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The async driver does not seem to block any thread.
I was misleading by the documentation explaining: "The maximum time that a thread may wait for a connection to become available."
(http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/com/mongodb/connection/ConnectionPoolSettings.html#getMaxWaitTime-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-)

Jeff wrote a program showing that no thread are blocked: https://gist.github.com/jyemin/139b7bc2a94d49f5903f. The setting only set a timeout for the callback.